# Output shows instance at 0xa19124c as output

Tags: python-3.x, object, instance

friends. I have two doubts in Python about the output of my project. I have two files:

Bank.py

```
class clients:
    def __init__(self,name, telephone):
        self.name= name
        self.telephone= telephone

class account:
    def __init__(self, users, number, balance=0):
        self.users= users
        self.number=number
        self.balance=balance

    def resume(self):
        print('Number: %s. balance: %s' %(self.users, self.balance))
```

and the BankClients.py:

```
from Bank import clients
from Bank import account

client1= clients('john', '555-0804')
account1= account([client1], 1, 3000)

account1.resume()
```

The problem, the output shows:

```
Number: [<Bank.clients instance at 0xa19124c>]. balance: 3000
```

when it should be:

```
Number: 1. balance:3000
```

I have run in other computer and the problem is the same. I tried writing in the bank.py file in the print(xxx) line

```
print('number ... balance...'%(self.balance, self.balance))
```

and the output is the same, just with another code at instance for self.balance output.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just change it to `print('Number: %s. balance: %s' %(self.number, self.balance))`.

Comment: Thanks Jim!, but unfortunatelly its the same problem,

Answer (score 0):

you can decide what the output of `str(account1)` (or `repr(account1)` [that's what python uses when it prints a `list` of things] should look like by implementing your own `__str__` and `__repr__` functions.

for example: to customize `str(client)` you could do something like this:

```
class clients:
    def __init__(self,name, telephone):
        self.name= name
        self.telephone= telephone

    def __str__(self):
        return 'clients(name={}, telephone={})'.format(self.name,
                                                       self.telephone)
```

(and add something similar for `__repr__`).